# How to request "Snapshot Log" through AWS Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to request "Snapshot Logs" through [AWS SDK](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) somehow?

It's possible to do it through AWS console:

[image]

Cross posted to [Amazon forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106586).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requesting a log snapshot is a 3 step process.  First you have to do an environment information request:

```
elasticBeanstalk.requestEnvironmentInfo(
    new RequestEnvironmentInfoRequest()
        .withEnvironmentName(envionmentName)
        .withInfoType("tail"));
```

Then you have to retreive the environment information:

```
final List<EnvironmentInfoDescription> envInfos =
     elasticBeanstalk.retrieveEnvironmentInfo(
         new RetrieveEnvironmentInfoRequest()
             .withEnvironmentName(environmentName)
             .withInfoType("tail")).getEnvironmentInfo();
```

This returns a list of environment info descriptions, with the EC2 instance id and the URL to an S3 object that contains the log snapshot.  You can then retreive the logs with:

```
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler retryhandler = 
        new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(3, true);
    client.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryhandler);

    for (EnvironmentInfoDescription environmentInfoDescription : envInfos) {
        System.out.println(environmentInfoDescription.getEc2InstanceId());
         HttpGet rq = new HttpGet(environmentInfoDescription.getMessage());
         try {                    
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(rq);
             InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();                    
             System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(content));
         } catch ( Exception e ) {
             System.out.println("Exception fetching " + 
                 environmentInfoDescription.getMessage());
         }
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: the third step I would replace with `new URL(desc.getMessage()).getContent()`

Comment: it's important to notice that environment info is not available immediately, and we should loop and wait (~10-15 sec in my case)